# Cypress/percy authorization failed

Tags: authorization, cypress, php-8.1, percy

I have one question to cypress/percy. I use Cypress package version: 12.5.1, Percy:@percy/cli 1.20.0, php version PHP 8.1.16 (cli). I have one project with authentication and have to do snapshots with Percy. I have tried to use username and password in the method `cy.percySnapshot()`:

```
cy.visit('url');
cy.percySnapshot('name', {
    authorization: {
        username: '**********',
        password: '*********'
    }
});
```

My errors:

> [percy] Invalid snapshot options:
> [percy] - authorization: unknown property
>
> CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:  The response we
> received from your web server was:
>
> > 401: Unauthorized
>
> This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx`.
>
> If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option:
> `failOnStatusCode: false`

My package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@percy/cli": "^1.20.0",
    "@percy/cypress": "^3.1.2",
    "cypress": "^12.5.1"
  },
```

Snapshot is in the directory in percy but without css.

Has anyone else had such problems?

Thank you in advance for your help. If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: According to https://docs.percy.io/docs/capturing-assets-protected-with-authentication-clithis should work, no clue why it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted percy support and have got following answer:

```
cy.percySnapshot("Homepage responsive test", {
  discovery: {
    requestHeaders: {
      Authorization: "Basic ${Buffer.from('username:password').toString('base64')}"
    }
  }
});
```